# BLE scan works after bluetooth switch Off in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am using default **BluetoothLeScanner** for getting BLE device,After the scan starts I switch of the Bluetooth in mobile,But I am getting scan result in **ScanCallback** Listener.How is it working?Is there any way to trigger BLE without switch On Bluetooth?